# Selenium : How to wait then click?

Tags: python, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium for automation and i want to click in each one of the `<ul>`elements then wait before clicking again in the element. This is my code but it doesn't seem to be the solution :

```
def navBar():
 driver=setup()
 navBar_List = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav")
 listItem = navBar_List.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
 for item in listItem :
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME,"li")))
    item.click()
```

Here the HTLM code  :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
                <li tabindex="0">
                        <a class="h">
                            <div class="icon-left-navbar">
                                 ...
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li tabindex="0">
                        <a class="h">
                            <div class="icon-left-navbar">
                                 ...
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li tabindex="0">
                        <a class="h">
                            <div class="icon-left-navbar">
                                 ...
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `li` with `.find_elements`.

Use `xpath` for recognize them : `//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav']//li`.

With loop you can utilize increment to wait each `li`. I'm imagine it will produce like below:

```
(xpath)[1]
(xpath)[2]
etc...
```

And try the following code:

```
listItem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav']//li")))

for x in range(1, len(listItem)+1):
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav']//li)[" +str(x) +"]"))).click()
```

Comment: The `len(listItem)` is equal to 0

Comment: @AbdoRabah Code updated with add `WebDriverWait` to wait `listItem`, please try again and see what did go. Hope this helps.

Comment: @frianH..i fixed it the XPath is `listItem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/div/ul/li")`

Answer (score 0):

Is *Thread.sleep(100)* an option?